# How to import a file name according to a selected option value - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have two TextFields named Choose City and Choose District. They are all select textboxes.
At the same time, I have some file:

```
    // cities.js
    const cities = {
        "01": {
            "name": "City 1",
            "code": "01"
        },
        "02": {
            "name": "City 2",
            "code": "02"
        }
    }
    export default cities

    // 01.js
    const districts = {
        "001": {
            "name": "District 1",
            "code": "001"
        },
        "002": {
            "name": "District 2",
            "code": "002"
        }
    }
    export default districts

    // 02.js
    const districts = {
        "003": {
            "name": "District 3",
            "code": "003"
        },
        "004": {
            "name": "District 4",
            "code": "004"
        }
    }
    export default districts
```

I want them to work like:
- After choosing a city "City 1" from the Textfield Choose City. I will open a file names "01.js" to get it's districts, then display them to the Textfield Choose District.
- Similar with when choosing a city with code value "xx", I will open file names "xx.js" to get it's districts.

```
const handleChangeCity = city =>{
    // import file xx.js here to display it's list districts

}
```

Question: 
How to import a JavaScript file into a function according to our selected option?
Could anyone of you help me?

Comment: maybe using [Dynamic Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) in some way

Comment: your 01.js and 02.js don't export anything, so ... how do you expect to access the data inside?

Comment: @bravo I have exported them in my code, I just didn't write it here

Comment: oh, wait, you're using `require` rather than import/export - disregard the dynamic imports suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Either you `require`/`import` them before building your code, so that you can just use the data based on what is selected, or you could load the data via AJAX when it gets selected!

**EDIT:**

With lots of district files I would suggest loading them when needed! Maybe like this:

```js
const handleChangeCity = city => {
  fetch(`http://path/to/district/files/${city}.js`)
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

Also, making the district files JSON (if possible) would be easier to work with.

```js
const handleChangeCity = city => {
  fetch(`http://path/to/district/files/${city}.json`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

Or with `async`/`await`:

```js
const handleChangeCity = async (city) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`http://path/to/district/files/${city}.json`)
    const districts = await response.json()

    console.log(districts)
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: But I have hundreds file .js, I thinks import all of them is not good :/

Comment: Ok then I would suggest loading them when needed via AJAX

Comment: @OangPhạm see my edit but maybe make the district files JSON that's easier to work with!

Comment: I have tried your solution but it always has: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: @OangPhạm can I see your JSON please? And if there is a `<` I guess you are fetching HTML try to open the URL to your JSON file in the browser to see if it has the right content.

Comment: ``` {
        "02": {
            "name": "District2",
            "code": "02"
        }
    }```
this is my json format

Comment: @OangPhạm then please check the response from the JSON file in your browser I guess the response contains HTML